Installing SpaCy in Fedora 41
I am getting into troubles as I try to install spaCy in a Fedora 41, AMD Ryzen machine. I got this:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
          × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
          │ exit code: 1
          ╰─> [22 lines of output]
              + /home/herlimenezes/AmbientesVirtuais/PNL-env/bin/python /tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466/vendored-meson/meson/meson.py setup /tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466 /tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466/.mesonpy-2yo3onu6 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466/.mesonpy-2yo3onu6/meson-python-native-file.ini
              The Meson build system
              Version: 1.4.99
              Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466
              Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-oviwb629/numpy_b484673443964b1592ca24f081a16466/.mesonpy-2yo3onu6

How to get rid of this?

Complete output can be seen at:
https://paste.centos.org/view/cd08625d

I guess the trouble comes from Fedora 41 packaging because I set up a virtual Ubuntu 24.02 virtual machine as well as a Python Virtual Environment, and it run smoothly.
